# Implementing ast.literal_eval on a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

With the following expression, you can convert a string to a python dict.

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = ast.literal_eval("{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}")
>>> a
{'muffin': 'lolz', 'foo': 'kitty'}
```

And with the following expression, you can get the "foo" value:

```
>>> a.get('foo')
```

I have an array of strings which are similar to python dict format.

Firstly, I want to convert all of them to dict, so I will be able to create a dict array.

Secondly, I want to get all "foo" values from that dict array, so I will be able to create a "foo" array.

How can I manage this?

Thanks,

Comment: look into list and dict comprehensions.... or for loops, but comprehensions are easier...

Comment: "I have an array of strings which are similar to python dict format. " doesn't happen to be JSON? Why not include a short sample of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this approximately what you're after?

```
import ast
import numpy
a = numpy.array(["{'foo':123}","{'foo':234}"])
numpy.fromiter((ast.literal_eval(s)['foo'] for s in a), numpy.int_)
```

(Of course the appropriate dtype will depend on what's actually in those dicts.)