# Implementing ast.literal_eval on a numpy array involves lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array similar to the following:

```
Y = ['[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', '[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0]', ...]
```

Each element of the array involves string of a python list.

Is there any very fast way to convert them into real list by using ast.literal_eval?

Comment: Numpy has its own eval but if your lists are as posted splitting and mapping to into will be way faster

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573764/implementing-ast-literal-eval-on-a-numpy-array?

Comment: If you just have strings as posted just use `list(map(int, sub.strip('[]'.split(',')))` where each sub is a string in your main array/list, it will be way faster than any eval

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: `Y[:] = (list(map(int, sub.strip('[]').split(','))) for sub in Y)`

Comment: I am on my phone so there may be a typo or two but that is the general idea.